# In meteor if I use template name instead of body then its not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am in a basic level and having a problem and that is , In meteor if I use template name instead of body in Javascript file then its not working..

here is my html code :

```
    <head>
  <title>simple</title>
</head> 

<body>
  <ul>

    {{#each player}}

      <li> {{text}}</li>


    {{/each}}

  </ul>
</body>

<template name="shahin">

  {{player}}

</template>
```

javascript code:

```
Template.shahin.helpers({
      player: [
         { text: "This is paragraph 1..." },
         { text: "This is paragraph 2..." },
         { text: "This is paragraph 3..." },
         { text: "This is paragraph 4..." },
         { text: "This is paragraph 5..." }
      ]
   });
```

Now if i run this code then it does not show anything. But i change to my Tamplate name with this

```
Template.body.helpers
```

then the code is working. Can somebody please explain why is this like so? let me know why this is not working :

```
Template.shahin.helpers
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you are not calling the template anywhere in your body.

Try this:

```
     <head>
  <title>simple</title>
</head> 

<body>
  {{> shahin}} <!-- this is where the contents of template="shahin" will render. If you don't call this, "shahin" will never get displayed -->
</body>

<template name="shahin">

  <ul>

    {{#each player}}

      <li> {{text}}</li>


    {{/each}}

  </ul>

</template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. one more thing. can you please tell me how to display the property name as well as the property value? in above case, i just have 'text' as property. what if i have different properties along with different values. then how will do show the properties: values in the body?

Comment: So then you need to call that property. If your object of array is going to be like: ```[{text: "abc", "name":"spiderman","contact":121},{text:"def","name":"doge","contact":132}]``` then you call it using: ```{{#each player }} <li>{{text}} , {{name}}, {{contact}} </li>```